# Type Error : document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example of Line Graph</h2>    
<script src="../../../Scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var monthsData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
            strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
            pointColor: "#fff",
            pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
            data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
        }
        ]
    };
    var months = document.getElementById("chartData").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);
</script>
<div>
     <canvas id="chartData" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have seen previous error regarding the same issue and corrected all those but mine is not resolved. I'm using chart.js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Code Like This

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example of Line Graph</h2>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>

<div>
     <canvas id="chartData" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var monthsData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
            strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
            pointColor: "#fff",
            pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
            data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
        }
        ]
    };
    var months = document.getElementById("chartData").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now im facing like "chart is not defined" in the line of "        new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);"

Comment: is chart library i.e Chart.min.js loading?

Comment: its not loading sir

Comment: sir how to make Chart library to load

Comment: check path of Chart library may be improper

Comment: I had downloaded Chart.js and Chart.min.js from NewGet package so it was not working, after using cdn path its working fine, thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Place your `script` tag below the `div` that contains the `canvas` element.

You are getting the error because at the time the script is interpreted and executed, the canvas does not exist in the DOM.

The [MDN page about script tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) states that:

> Scripts without async or defer attributes, as well as inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.

This being said, my answer presents the cause of the error and a simple workaround. Check out [Satpal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718272/390819) for a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the issue as when the statement `document.getElementById("chartData")` is executed the DOM is yet not loaded. So its not able to find the element.

You should use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    var monthsData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
                    strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
                    pointColor: "#fff",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
                    data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
                }
            ]
    };
    var months = document.getElementById("chartData").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now its showing Reference Error : Chart is not defined in the line "new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);"

Comment: @PruthviRaj, Is chart library loading?

Comment: Sir How to check whether the library is properly loaded or not.                    I have a copy of chart.js and chart.min.js and both these files are referenced (or) included in the script tag.

Comment: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: chart library is not loaded

Comment: I'm new to this sir how to make it load.

Comment: @PruthviRaj, Try once with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve the element before it's loading. So load the script after page load by using **[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)** event handler .

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.(*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload#Notes)*)

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {    
    var monthsData = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
      datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
        strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
        pointColor: "#fff",
        pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
        data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
      }]
    };
    var months = document.getElementById("chartData").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Now its showing Reference Error : Chart is not defined in the line         "new Chart(months).Line(monthsData);"

Comment: @PruthviRaj : you need to include chart library before the script

Comment: @PruthviRaj : glad to help :)